# Keep drop down option

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 3 pages, register.php, view.php and edit.php

I want to keep dropdown option in edit.php
It takes the first option.

My pages:

REGISTER.PHP

```html
<form id="base" method="post" action="insert.php">
        <input data-validate="number" id="contract" name="contract">
                    <input data-validate="text" id="client" name="client">
          <select  name="step">
             <option value="option1">OPTION1</option>
          <option value="option2">OPTION2</option>
              </select>
       <button data-validate="submit">Register</button>
       </form>
```

EDIT.PHP

```html
<form id="base" name="base" method="post" action="">
     <input data-validate="number" value="<?php echo $contract; ?>" readonly="true" id="contract">
        <input data-validate="text"  value="<?php echo $client; ?>" id="client">
           <select  name="step">
             <option value="option1">Option1</option>
          <option value="option2">Option2</option>
              </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: In register.php i chose an option,i save it in database,  when i want to edit data from database(edit.php), it takes the first option of the drop down, not what i choosed in register.  I hope now is clear. THX. I'm going to edit through view.php where i have listed all database entries and edit button for each entry.

Comment: You can select one of options with `selected` attribute. Like this: `<option value="option2" selected="selected">Option2</option>`. You have to do it programmatically based on the value stored in DB.

Comment: yes but i don't know how, in db it pass as varchar, not as drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, assuming `$step` to be the value from the database.

```
<form id="base" name="base" method="post" action="">
    <input data-validate="number" value="<?php echo $contract; ?>" readonly="true" id="contract">
    <input data-validate="text"  value="<?php echo $client; ?>" id="client">
                      <select  name="step">
                        <?php
                            $options = array("option1" =>  "Option1", "option2" => "Option2");
                            foreach($options as $v => $c)
                                echo "<option value='$v'" . ($step == $v ? " selected='selected'" : "") . ">$c</option>";
                        ?>
                      </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for each option in the selection but it could ve been easier if your select was dynamic:

......
     >OPTION 1
 repeat this with all you options although its much cleaner to use a function which takes the option value as an argumant

Comment: How to use a function that do it?  I don't know how. THX.